# How set a grandchild div vertically centered regardless of its height using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to set a Grand Child div vertically centered regardless of its height when Grand Parent div's position is relative and Parent div's position is absolute.

```css
.gParent {
    position: relative;
}

.parent {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 10% 5%;
    width: 100%;
}

.gChild {
    padding: 5px 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div class="gParent">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="gChild">Text Only Content</div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: you want the gChild div to be vertically centered within the gParent div, while the parent div is positioned absolute?  I don't think this is possible with those constraints.  Do you need the parent absolutely positioned?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I really need parent div positioned absolutely. If it is not possible, do you have any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

```
.gChild {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nL578wjj/

Comment: The fiddle assumes that the height of the gParent div will be set to a height greater than the gParent/gChild.. is that a valid assumption?  Otherwise it breaks out on top and bottom if there is too much content in the gChild.